# Set all Object keys to false

Tags: javascript, lodash

Lets say I have an object

```
  filter: {
    "ID": false,
    "Name": true,
    "Role": false,
    "Sector": true,
    "Code": false
  }
```

I want to set all keys to false (to reset them). What's the best way to do this, I'd like to avoid looping with `foreach` and stuff. Any neat one liner?

Comment: thanks, please write an answer!

Comment: How about this, `filter: {}` if you had handled the `filter` for the same?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Using lodash, `mapValues` is a graceful, loop-free way:

```
filter = {
    "ID": false,
    "Name": true,
    "Role": false,
    "Sector": true,
    "Code": false
};

filter = _.mapValues(filter, () => false);
```

If you want to do this with Underscore.js, there is an equivalent, but with a slightly different name:

```
filter = _.mapObject(filter, () => false);
```

In either case, the value of `filter` will be set to:

```
{ ID: false, 
  Name: false, 
  Role: false, 
  Sector: false, 
  Code: false }
```

Comment: thanks for that. one question, if i want to obtain the property that has value "true" (only one at any time), how best to do it?

Comment: The example data belie the assertion that only one property is `true` at a time.  But regardless of however many are, `_.keys(filter).filter(k => filter[k])` will give you a quick array of all keys to values that are truthy. You can use exact equivalence to `true` if you want strictly booleans. And you can always index the resulting array to get the first one: `_.keys(filter).filter(k => filter[k])[0]`.  That returns `undefined` if there are none. Sorry for the three instances of "filter" in that expression, but your variable name overloads the function name.

Comment: @chefcurry7 You might also like `_.find(_.keys(filter), k => filter[k])`. It works similarly, but slighly shorter.

Comment: This is the best solution if you use lodash!

Answer (score 72):

Well here's a one-liner with vanilla JS:

```
Object.keys(filter).forEach(v => filter[v] = false)
```

It does use an implicit loop with the `.forEach()` method, but you'd have to loop one way or another (unless you reset by replacing the whole object with a hardcoded default object literal).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this can't be done **WITHOUT** looping. Not sure if the OP understands this.

Comment: @CarlEdwards that's fine carl. I didn't realise arrow functions were this useful.

Comment: Even without an arrow function it is still pretty short, as in the other answer.

Comment: Yeah in this case the arrow syntax is almost identical to the traditional `function() {}`. Just a little less typing.

Answer (score 12):

If you're not using ES6, here is its ES5 counterpart.

```js
Object.keys(filter).forEach(function(key, value) {
    return filter[key] = false;
})
```

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to modify the array, here's an ES6 alternative that returns a new one:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(filter).map((key) => [key, false]))
```

Explanation:

`Object.keys` returns the object's keys:

```
Object.keys({ a: 1, b: 2 }) // returns ["a", "b"]
```

Then we map the result `["a", "b"]` to `[key, false]`:

```
["a", "b"].map((key) => [key, false]) // returns [['a', false], ['b', false]]
```

And finally we call `Object.fromEntries` that maps an array of arrays with the form `[key, value]` to an Object:

```
Object.fromEntries([['a', false], ['b', false]]) // returns { a: false, b: false }
```

Comment: this is the best answer so far!

Answer (score 5):

A small line of code compatible with all browsers:

```
for(var i in your_object) your_object[i] = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

With ES6 features one-liner without mutation:

```
{
  ...Object.keys(filter).reduce((reduced, key) => ({ ...reduced, [key]: false }), {})
}
```

Comment: ` ...Object.keys(filter).reduce((reduced, key) => ({ ...reduced, [key]: false }), {})` should suffce. No need to wrap it in an object

Comment: This worked for my use-case, requiring immutability, though the OP did not state that as a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

hasOwnProperty must be used

```

```
for(var i in your_object) {
  if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(your_object, i)) {
    your_object[i] = false;
  }
}
```

```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are dealing with 'scope' variables, this might be a better solution.

```
Object.keys(filter).reduce(function(accObj, parseObj) {
                accObj[parseObj] = false;
                return accObj;
              }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i would call a neat one-liner solution:

```
const filtered = Object.assign(...Object.keys(filter).map(k => ({ [k]: false })));
```

Demo:

```js
const filter = {
  'ID': false,
  'Name': true,
  'Role': false,
  'Sector': true,
  'Code': false
};

const filtered = Object.assign(...Object.keys(filter).map(k => ({ [k]: false })));

console.log(filtered);
```

We are basically converting the object into an array using `Object.assign()` so we can use the `map()` fucntion on it to set each propety value to false, then we convert the array back to an object using the `Object.assign()` with the spread operator :)