# How to modify all properties of an object in a functional way

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function which create a new object with all properties of `in` set to `true`, the function should create a new object.

How to do it with vanilla js? I can use deconstruction and latest JS.

```
   const in = {
        ida:true,
        idb:false,
        idc:false,
        ide:true
    }
```

result wanted

```
const out = {
    ida:true,
    idb:true,
    idc:true,
    ide:true
}
```

Comment: I have tried with reduce but no result.. :(

Comment: Please publish, what you try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set all Object keys to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836239/set-all-object-keys-to-false)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: "How to do it with vanilla js?" — Use an immutable library. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There is no need for a library @Quentin, is basic js functionality.

Comment: @J.Pichardo — Only if none of your properties have values which are objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could use `Object.keys` and the spread operator to accomplish this:

```js
const input = {
  ida: true,
  idb: false,
  idc: false,
  ide: true
}

const out = Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, key) => ({...acc, [key]: true}), {});

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map all keys with an new object and `false` as value. Later assign them to a single object.

```js
const
    inO = { ida: true, idb: false, idc: false, ide: true },
    outO = Object.assign(...Object.keys(inO).map(k => ({ [k]: true })));
    
console.log(outO);
```

Comment: thanks, but I this warning Expected at least 1 arguments but got 0 or more any idea?

Comment: I am using typescript

Comment: With destructuring I find it more elegant to use { ...Object.keys } instead of Object.assign

Comment: @Radex, sorry, can not help with *typescript*.

Comment: @Radex in what function call are you getting that error?

Comment: @NinaScholz right, hard to get it working here. Another solution is reduce : `Object.keys(inO).reduce((m, k) => ({...m, [k]: true}), {})`

Comment: @Logar that's the same as my answer :)

Comment: @J.Pichardo ah yeah, just noticed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for..in loop which iterates over the keys of an object:

```js
function setTrue(obj) {
  for (k in obj) obj[k] = true;
}

const o = {
  ida: true,
  idb: false,
  idc: false,
  ide: true
}

setTrue(o);
console.log(o);
```