# Toggle multiple Boolean values in an object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that comes like this:

```
let sizes = {
'30': false,
'36': false,
'40': false
}
```

I was wandering is it possible to toggle all of them with one function, so that only **one value is true at a time,** while not depending on the key and the length of the object?

It seems that For-in loop would be great for that, I'm just not sure how to approach it.

I've been sitting on this problem for a couple of hours, and cannot seem to find something similar. 
Thank you!

Comment: What will determine which value should be the only true value?

Comment: That's invalid syntax.  Numbers as object keys must be quoted.  You also need commas separating the attributes .

Comment: A [comment on the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836239/set-all-object-keys-to-false#comment68890364_40836350) to the duplicate question addresses the issue of one property remaining `true`.

Comment: Why this question is close ? the question was how to toggle not how to set all key to false.