# Object destructuring with logical NOT all elements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object:

```
const hide_account_settings_tabs = {
 'links' :true,
 'media' :true,
 'status':true,
}
```

In another file I receive the object and assign every value + logical NOT on each element.

```
let showLinks = !hide_account_settings_tabs['links'];
let showMedia = !hide_account_settings_tabs['media'];
let showStatus = !hide_account_settings_tabs['status'];
```

Looking for a nice way to replace the 3 lines above with object destructuring. is this possible?
Something like:

```
let { showLinks, showMedia, showStatus} = !hide_account_settings_tabs;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set all Object keys to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836239/set-all-object-keys-to-false)

Comment: @Mathieu i think he needs to invert

Comment: The answers in the question linked can still be adapted to this use case I think. But it is not a 1-1 equivalence, indeed.

Comment: `const {showLinks,showMedia,showStatus} = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(hide_account_settings_tabs).map(([k,v]) => ['show'+k[0].toUpperCase()+k.substring(1),!v]))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Object.keys or Object.values but you can maybe face problems if order is not conserved

```js
const hide_account_settings_tabs = {
 'links' :true,
 'media' :true,
 'status':true,
}
let [ showLinks, showMedia, showStatus ] = Object.keys(hide_account_settings_tabs)
.map(elem =>!hide_account_settings_tabs[elem]);
console.log( showLinks, showMedia, showStatus )
```

```js
const hide_account_settings_tabs = {
 'links' :true,
 'media' :true,
 'status':true,
}
let [ showLinks, showMedia, showStatus ] = Object.values(hide_account_settings_tabs)
.map(elem =>!elem);
console.log( showLinks, showMedia, showStatus )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` to convert your object into an array of key-value pairs, then update the keys and invert the value. Then use `Object.fromEntries` to create a new object you then finally can destructure. This approach does not depend on any particular order of properties.

```
const { showlinks, showmedia, showstatus } = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(hide_account_settings_tabs).map(e => [`show${e[0]}`, !e[1]]));
```

Does it provide the required functionality? Yes. Is it elegant? IMHO, no ...